# Android binding service

Tags: android, service, binding

I have one service and two activities. I from one Activity go to another, and in the onStop method, do unbindService. 
When I came in the second Activivity the service destroyed. 
When the second activity calls the bindservice, a new service is created.

How to make so  that the service is not destroyed?

Comment: start it first... then bind to it

Comment: @rub had you checked my answer is it working at your end

Answer (score 0):

If you want that service should not stop when migrating to next activtiy,then you should use IntentService instead of Service.

InetntService don't have any UI,so it will contiously runs in the background without user interaction and when it finishes then you have to store its data somewhere (or you can use the broadcast reciver )and populate that data in the next actvity if you need.